# Large active directory domain with redhat 7.3 or 7.4

Tags: linux, active-directory, redhat

We setup 12 redhat servers and joined them to our windows active directory domain. Initially we used redhat 7.4 and everything was fine but then the vendor came in and told us their app only supports 7.3. So we reinstall all 12 servers as 7.3 and connect them to the domain. All working except the users now get random UID on each server. This isn't going to work as we have a shared file system across the 12 servers.

We have set this up using `sssd`. Setup was pretty easy, we just installed a few packages then ran this command to join:

```
realm join --user=xxxxxx--computer-ou="ou=EpicWorkloads,ou=EPIC,dc=core,dc=dir,dc=xxxxxx,dc=com" core.dir.xxxxx.com
```

Then changed a few settings in */etc/sssd/sssd.conf* to work with a large domain:

```
ldap_idmap_default_domain = core.dir.xxxxx.com
ldap_idmap_autorid_compat = true
ldap_idmap_range_min = 200000
ldap_idmap_range_max = 2000200000
ldap_idmap_range_size = 1000000
```

The problem appears to be that last value. On 7.4 we could set it to 128,000,000. On 7.3 it fails if we set it over 1 million.

Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the RHEL 7.4 release notes: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.4_release_notes/new_features_authentication_and_interoperability

You didn't say if you're setting POSIX User/Group IDs for your users in AD; perhaps you are not.

In particular, the section "SSSD supports user and group resolution, authentication, and authorization in setups without UIDs or SIDs" may be relevant:

> In traditional System Security Services Daemon (SSSD) deployments,
>   users and groups either have POSIX attributes set or SSSD can resolve
>   the users and groups based on Windows security identifiers (SID). With
>   this update, in setups that use LDAP as the identity provider, SSSD
>   now supports the following functionality even when UIDs or SIDs are
>   not present in the LDAP directory: User and group resolution through
>   the D-Bus interface Authentication and authorization through the
>   plugabble authentication module (PAM) interface (BZ#1425891)

There are quite a number of SSSD-related changes in 7.4 (particularly around smart cards)